# Direct product and absolut norm

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem

Let $K$ be an algebraic number field and $\mathfrak{a} \neq 0$ an ideal of $\mathcal{O}_K$, with prime factorization $\mathfrak{a} = \mathfrak{p}_1^{v_1}*...*\mathfrak{p}_r^{v_r}$. Assume $r=2$.

By the chinese reminder theorem we see that $\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{a} \cong \mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{p}_1^{v_1}\bigoplus\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{p}_2^{v_2}$.

If I know the absolute norm $\mathcal{R}$($\mathfrak{p}_i)^{v_i}$ for $i \in \{1, 2\}$, why then is $\mathcal{R}$($\mathfrak{a})=$$\mathcal{R}$($\mathfrak{p}_1)^{v_1}*\mathcal{R}$($\mathfrak{p}_2)^{v_2}$

Thanks for your help, or any hints!

Comment: What is your definition of the absolute norm? Do you want $R(\mathfrak b) = |\mathcal O_K/\mathfrak b|$.

Comment: Yes that is my definition!

Answer (score 1):

By defintion, the absolute norm $\mathcal R(\mathfrak a)$= card $(\mathfrak o_K/\mathfrak a)$, so that $\mathcal R(\mathfrak a)$ is obviously the product of the $\mathcal R({\mathfrak p_i}^{n_i})$. To show that $\mathcal R({\mathfrak p}^{n})= \mathcal R({\mathfrak p})^n$, consider, in the chain of descending ideals $o_K > \mathfrak p > ... > \mathfrak p^i > ... > {\mathfrak p}^n$, the successive quotients $\mathfrak p^i / \mathfrak p^{i+1}$. Multiplication by  $\mathfrak p$ induces readily an isomorphism  $o_K / \mathfrak p \cong \mathfrak p^i / \mathfrak p^{i+1}$, and we are done.

Comment: Thanks, but could you explain me the obviously in the first line? Why is card $(\mathfrak o_K/\mathfrak a)$ = $(\mathfrak o_K/\mathfrak p_1)$ * $(\mathfrak o_K/\mathfrak p_2)$

Comment: Because for finite rings $A,B$,  $|A\oplus B| = |A||B|$.